# How do I specify my logger configuration file location in application.conf in Play?

Tags: playframework-2.0, playframework-2.2

https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.2.x/SettingsLogger

According to the link above, one can set the location of the logging configuration using -Dlogger.blahblah from command line. I want this to be set in my application.conf instead as I only want to set all configuration in one file per environment.

How do I do this and is it even possible?

Comment: Where is your logging configuration? What is the name of the file?

Comment: @mantithetical logger.xml. For different environment, I want it to be something like logger-prod.xml but I don't want to specify that using command line but should be configured in application-prod.conf. The goal is to simplify the command line and put as much as configuration possible in application-${env}.conf file.

Comment: I see; I am not aware of any easy way to do this other than by using java system properties. Typically, env logic is wrapped by a bash script or by whatever deployment tool (puppet, chef etc.) you are using. +1 for your question though.

Answer (score 0):

Just rename yours logback.xml file to logback-play-dev.xml https://github.com/playframework/playframework/blob/master/framework/src/play/src/main/scala/play/api/Logger.scala#L227

So play-dev will be invoked only if your app mode is Development